# Instagram API Standard Object

Tags: php, object, instagram

I am attempting to parse the Instagram API standard object that looks like this:

```
    stdClass Object
(
[pagination] => stdClass Object
        (
            [next_url] => https://api.instagram.com/v1/users /283549787/media/recent?access_token=3036118427.1677ed0.fceea7d5e10440b691a670ddb6a97783&max_id=1059902719332635377_283549787
        [next_max_id] => 1059902719332635377_283549787
    )

[meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 200
    )

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [attribution] => 
                [tags] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => vbb
                        [1] => 100k
                        [2] => ig
                    )

                [type] => image
                [location] => 
                [comments] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [count] => 22
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [created_time] => 1461241283
                                        [text] => weeeelll ðŸ’¥
                                        [from] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [username] => thewolfcult
                                                [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12519175_228551560821189_1928102794_a.jpg
                                                [id] => 2685463016
                                                [full_name] => Wolf Cult
                                            )

                                        [id] => 17846791729091814
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [created_time] => 1461241621
                                        [text] => this pic is LOL ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜‚
                                        [from] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [username] => class_y_man
                                                [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13129374_610084285824464_241975035_a.jpg
                                                [id] => 189866780
                                                [full_name] => Z.k
                                            )

                                        [id] => 17846791822091814
                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [created_time] => 1461241649
                                        [text] => Love it ðŸ˜
                                        [from] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [username] => kosmonelle
                                                [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13113731_1661552477439373_875045798_a.jpg
                                                [id] => 2371520392
                                                [full_name] => 
                                            )

                                        [id] => 17846791834091814
                                    )

                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [created_time] => 1461254879
                                        [text] => ðŸ†ðŸ‘
                                        [from] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [username] => modelsandphotographers1
                                                [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11336128_1774042986155389_99539322_a.jpg
                                                [id] => 1418124928
                                                [full_name] => Best Models & Photographers
                                            )

                                        [id] => 17846795935091814
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [filter] => Normal
                [created_time] => 1461230731
                [link] => https://www.instagram.com/p/BEdQrSDytME/
                [likes] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [count] => 16672
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [username] => jassi_bains_official
                                        [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12327958_458252344360785_973161765_a.jpg
                                        [id] => 2302067650
                                        [full_name] => Jassi bains
                                    )

                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [username] => ukay.tlb527
                                        [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg
                                        [id] => 3101669439
                                        [full_name] => Melvin Rosetta
                                    )

                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [username] => hahmedhossam121414411
                                        [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg
                                        [id] => 3150267725
                                        [full_name] => Bobby Ivan
                                    )

                                [3] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [username] => somi__0
                                        [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13102392_989473131142748_1189753865_a.jpg
                                        [id] => 2190016506
                                        [full_name] => Somi  ðŸ‘¸ðŸ¼ðŸ’•
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [images] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [low_resolution] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12918470_1000175006702614_1067887222_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMzIxNTIxNjA0MjAzODAyMA%3D%3D.2.l
                                [width] => 320
                                [height] => 320
                            )

                        [thumbnail] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c190.0.644.644/12918387_1540009256304246_510188281_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMzIxNTIxNjA0MjAzODAyMA%3D%3D.2.c
                                [width] => 150
                                [height] => 150
                            )

                        [standard_resolution] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [url] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12918470_1000175006702614_1067887222_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTIzMzIxNTIxNjA0MjAzODAyMA%3D%3D.2.l
                                [width] => 640
                                [height] => 640
                            )

                    )

                [users_in_photo] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [caption] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [created_time] => 1461230731
                        [text] => really , thank you ðŸ† #ig #100k #vbb
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [username] => mattiacanfa
                                [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13113786_488414981352515_1701597009_a.jpg
                                [id] => 283549787
                                [full_name] => Mattia Canfarotta
                            )

                        [id] => 17846789149091814
                    )

                [user_has_liked] => 
                [id] => 1233215216042038020_283549787
                [user] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [username] => mattiacanfa
                        [profile_picture] => https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13113786_488414981352515_1701597009_a.jpg
                        [id] => 283549787
                        [full_name] => Mattia Canfarotta
                    )

            )



)
```

I am trying to get standard_resolution url like this with $json_result being the object:

```
foreach ($json_result->data->images->standard_resolution->url as $images){

print_r($images);

}
```

For some reason nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve because data is an array it needs to be this:

```
foreach ($json_result->data as $data){

foreach ($data->images->standard_resolution as $link){
echo "<img src='$link'></img>";

}
}
```